# What's the equivalent of Alt+left/right arrow key like Eclipse in WebStorm?

Tags: eclipse, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

In Eclipse you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><-</kbd> or <kbd>-></kbd> to move between places you were. What is the equivalent in WebStorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right`</kbd>.

But you can configure that in `settings` -> `keymap`:

[image]

You can also import the settings of Eclipse via the select box on top.